# Scrape birth date from twitter profiles using selenium

Tags: python, api, selenium, web-scraping, twitter

i have been trying to extract the birth date of a twitter profile using python and selenium.

I tried this
document.getElementsByClassName("css-901oao css-16my406 r-1re7ezh r-4qtqp9 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-zso239 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0")[0].innerText

But the class changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many locators from social media platforms are dynamically generated.
You can try to use this:

```
//div[@data-testid='UserProfileHeader_Items']//span[contains(text(), 'Born')]
```

Is going from main div parent to that one where Born string is always present (to avoid finding any other locators where Born word is present, for example a status)